# C++ program parsing arguments

Tags: c++, parsing

I want to make a program to be called from the command line like this:

```
myprogram.exe -F/-T FILE/TEXT -W FILE.WAV -P FILE.PHO -A
```

They are 3 parts:

- myprogram.exe
- -F OR -T and the File or text
- -W FILE -P FILE and -A (At least one, up to 3, in any order (or not, if it's complicated))

So it can be:

```
myprogram.exe -T "Text Text, test text" -A
```

or:

```
myprogram.exe -F FILENAME -A
```

or:

```
myprogram.exe -F FILENAME -P FILENAME -W FILENAME
```

etc.

`-A` is one function (needs the text or the file)
`-W` writes a WAV file with the info from the text/file
`-P` does something similar to `-W`

What is the best way to handle it? Analyzing `argv[x]` one by one, and deciding with `if`s? Something easier?

I am **new** to programming and using VS2008.

Comment: I'm missing the difference between your first two invocations.

Answer (score 6):

You can parse them manually or use [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I can use this kind of libraries, but I will take a look. I have read that is a bit complicated for newbies... a very simple example somewhere? :)

Answer (score 2):

> > Analyizing argv[x] one by one

That's what I would do. Maybe maintain a counter of the current element ...

```
unsigned int cur = 0;

if (argc <= 1) {
  .. error 
}

if (!strncmp(argv[cur],"-T",2)) {
  .. process
  ++cur;
}

...

for (;cur < argc;++cur) {
   if (!strncmp(argv[cur],"-F",2)) {
      .. process

   }  
   else if ...
}
```

There are some command line parers out there. Unix has `getopt`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `getopt` if you can: it's simple enough. It'll handle combined options too (like in `ls -lt` instead of `ls -l -t`) and it handles options with arguments as well, and the order in which they appear also doesn't matter. All this makes it "standard" to people used to command line arguments (normally order of options is irrelevant, except when giving contradictory options...).

Answer (score 0):

this is already done by others, so I wouldn't spend all your time on it if I were you.
Look at Boost's ProgramOptions for example.